# Need to remove password on my Samsung s4

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-4

While trying to remove the password on my device, it's giving me a message stating that it's "administration or encrypted is blocked."
Yes I have encrypted my phone

So please give me a solution to remove the password on my phone.

Comment: What do you mean by, removing password? Removing from where?

Answer (score 1):

1) Go to settings>security

2) Find "Clear Credentials" and select ok to clear credentials

3) Go back to security setting and find "Device Administrators" and clear (disable) all checked boxes.

4) POWER OFF PHONE! I had tried everything up to this point multiple times and it does not work!

5) Once powered on again go into the security setting and find "Clear Credentials" and once again clear

6) Go to "Screen Lock" and the options should be available once again.

I hope its help you.
if its work, Mark it as correct, please.